# In Turkish, regarding the locative, how do we know which suffix (-de or -da) should be used?

Tags: turkish

I'm studying Turkish, and regarding the locative, I've learned that it is implemented by adding the suffix -DA or -TA, the latter being used when the word starts with "p, ç, t, k, f, h, s, and ş".

So some examples from Duolingo are:

- Park means park and the locative used to say "in/at the park" is parkta
- Otel means hotel and the locative used to say "in/at the hotel" is otelde
- Banyo means bathroom and the locative used to say "in/at the bathroom" is banyoda
- Bakkal means store and the locative used to say "in/at the store" is bakkalda
- Okul means school and the locative used to say "in/at the school" is okulda

My question here is: sometimes the suffix is really -DA as in okulda, and sometimes the suffix is -DE as in otelde.

How does one decide if it should be -da or -de? Is any other possibility for the locative other than -da, -de, -ta and -te?

If so, for each word what decides the form of the suffix to be used?

Comment: There is no option other than -da -de -ta -te. The original suffix is condisederd to be -da. *d* becomes *t* when the rules are suitable for *consonant softening* (?). The vowel changes according to the big and small vowel harmony, so there is no choice other than *e* for main vowel being *a*

Comment: That's because /e/ and /a/ are non-high vowels; the other two, /ö/ and /o/, don't participate in vowel harmony (this is called "low vowel harmony"; "high vowel harmony" uses four vowels, not two: /i,ü, ɨ, u/). Look at the vowel in the syllable **before** -_de/da/te/ta_ -- you'll always see the same vowels before each variant. [Here's a few examples](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Turkish.html) to practice on.

Answer (score 15):

Turkish has a rule of [vowel harmony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_harmony#Turkish): it depends on the vowel of the preceding syllable. You get [a] after *u ı o a* and [e] after *ü i ö e*. There are some complications about final consonants in loan words which can be treated as exceptions. The t vs d thing has to do with whether there is a previous [voiceless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voicelessness) consonant. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_phonology) might clarify things for you.

Comment: Also, the Wikibooks article on [Turkish/Cases](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Turkish/Cases) has a nice overview.

Comment: It has lot's of mistakes: Essive, Inclusive, Abessive, Likeness, Coverage, Qualitative are not considered as cases in Turkish instead they are derivational affixes, means they create new words which have dictionary entries.

Answer (score 1):

For locatives, the basic suffix is –de/da (*otelde, okulda*) but after an unvoiced consonant (ç, f, h, k, p, s, ş or t)  the suffix appears as –te/ta (*otobüste*, *maçta*). Now for the vowel harmony.

a   is followed by a or ı

e   is followed by e or i

ı   is followed by ı or a

i   is followed by i or e

o   is followed by a or u

ö   is followed by ü or e

u   is followed by u or a

ü   is followed by ü or e

It will all become second nature once you practice it repeatedly.